# How can I work with sub-lists in a function in R?

Tags: r, function, data.table, sublist

I have a data table with lists and sub-list.

```
DT <- data.table (A=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5), B=c(200,210,300,420,289,365,587,250,110,500,800), C=c(0.6,0.35,0.6,0.85,0.22,0.36,0.39,0.31,0.33,0.58,0.66))
DT
DT_Split <- split(DT, DT$A)
names(DT_Split) <- c(paste("FF", names(DT_Split), sep = ""))
list2env(DT_Split, .GlobalEnv)
lapply(DT_Split, function(x){
  x[, NewColumn := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(B) < 0))]})
DT_Split2 <- lapply(DT_Split, function(x) split(x, x$NewColumn))
DT_Split2$FF1$`1`
```

How can I add a suffix to this sub-lists, `1` in `FF1` in `DT_Split2` (Last line)?
How can I address this sub-list in a function?

Update
I don't want to address or add a suffix manually. I mean something like this line:

```
names(DT_Split) <- c(paste("FF", names(DT_Split), sep = "")) 
list2env(DT_Split, .GlobalEnv)
```

but for sub-list.

Thanks a lot,
Milad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already used this in your `names(DT_Split) <-` line all you need to do is access the sublist if you want to change only `FF1` use the first line if you want to change all the sublists use `lapply`:

```
# paste0 is the equivalent to paste(..., sep="") but faster
# also no need to enclose it in c() call
names(DT_Split2$FF1) <- paste0(names(DT_Split2$FF1) , "Suff")
lapply(DT_Split2, function(x) {names(x)<-paste0(names(x) , "Suff"); x})
```

to extract the names of all sublists it can be easily achieved with :

```
lapply(name.of.list, names)
#lapply(DT_Split2, names)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to extract the names of all sublists? I need the names of all sublists to add in a function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works and I can see the names of sublists. Would you able please to help me with how can I use them in function?  For example, here `lapply(DT_Split, function(x){
  x[, NewColumn := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(B) < 0))]})'` I can use names of `DT_Split` but I can not use the name of sublists. Thanks again

Comment: what are you trying to achieve??

Comment: I want to define all my sublists as data tables with defined names. For example, if I have 10 sublists, I want to define all 10 sublists as table1...table10. then I can refer all of them in a function. But I don't want to make it manually.

Comment: For example, I can easily refer to them as data in a regression, ...

Comment: try `names(list.with.data.tables)<- paste0("table", 1:10)`. You can access them directly in lapply without knowing the names so I don't get how renaming them helps.

Comment: say I want to access third table i.e table3 I can use `list.with.data.tables[[paste0("table", 3)]]` `=>` to get the ith element `list.with.data.tables[[paste0("table", i)]]` or simply just `list.with.data.tables[[i]]`

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try it. Your answers were useful. Thanks again

Comment: An example would be using mtcars and regressing `mpg ~ cyl` after splitting the datasets over the number of gears :  `mt.split <- split(mtcars, mtcars$gear)` and then getting the summary for each model `lapply(mt.split, function(x) summary(lm(formula=mpg~cyl,data=x )))`

Comment: That's Great! Thanks again!